# Android Wear App Development

Tags: wear-os

I want to develop custom app in android wear (below 2.0 version). Is it possible to do with below 2.0 versions ?

Note: I already tried app using 2.0 preview version. Its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use an older version to develop custom apps in Android wear. However, there are limitations in using an [older version](https://www.apk4fun.com/history/48299/), unlike the version 2.0 you can access the internet directly over Bluetooth, WI-FI or cellular with relying on the [Data Layers APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html?utm_campaign=android%20wear_update_io16_051816&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog).

There are numerous updates were in you can only find in version 2.0. below is the link of what's new in Android Wear 2.0: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/android-wear-20-developer-preview.html